# Nested observeEvent() in observer() gets executed too often

Tags: r, reactive-programming, shiny-server, shiny

My code looks like

```
observe ({
    #subset someDataframe which I need in the observeEvent() 

    observeEvent(input$Numbers{
        #if not NULL, do something with subsetted dataframe
    })
})
```

I have an `observe()` function which gets input from the `ui.R`. Depending on the input, I subset a dataframe which will be displayed in the app. 
There is the need for further subsetting, but this field can be empty. To avoid the `Unhandled Error` if the selection is empty (thus, `NULL`) is use the `observeEvent()` function. If the field stays empty, there is no error raised.

There is some weird behaviour though. I print out what is selected (in my R console) observed by the `observeEvent()`. When I select something observed by the `observeEvent()` function, the selected stuff gets print out once. When I change a selection which is observed by the simple `observe()` and then change something in the selection observed by `observeEvent()` it gets printed out twice. When I change a selection observed by the `observe()` function and then the selection from the `observeEvent()` it gets printed out three times - and so forth.

So, depending on how often I change a selection observed by the `observed()` function I change, the `observeEvent()` gets executed that often.

Why is that?!

Comment: This is the first time I see a nested `observe` statements, I'm sure you can use `reactive` expressions instead.

Comment: @PorkChop a nested `reactive`? Or where would you use it?

Comment: `subset <- reactive({# Do your sub-setting here
if(!is.null(input$Numbers)){Do something else}
})` I presume you have some input triggers from `ui.r` that would do the initial sub-setting which you could bring into the `reactive` expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

```
subset <- reactive({
  # Do your sub-setting here 

  if(!is.null(input$Numbers)){
    #Do something else
  } 
  # return (your_subset)
})
```