# Nested observeEvent() in observeEvent() gets executed too often

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shiny-server

**EDIT** Reproducible example at the end.

I found a similar problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311142/nested-observeevent-in-observer-gets-executed-too-often), but using `reactive()` doesn't solve my issue.

I'm working on an app where users can upload files with a `FileInput`, so far it can handle FASTQ and CSV files (focus on CSV here). All uploaded files are saved as RData, which can then be selected in a `selectinput` where they're loaded again. This `selectinput` runs basically everything, since after it is evaluated it will trigger some reactive UI to display the CSV. I also noticed when printing that when I select a new file and then select rows it still prints the rows from the previous file.

I started using Shiny this January, I first followed the tutorial on the Shiny page and I've lurked several blogs and StackOverflow questions, so I'm confident that I'm making a ton of mistakes with the reactiveness and other Shiny specific things.

The `selectinput` observer:

```
observeEvent(input$selectfiles, ignoreInit = T, {
    if (!is.null(USER$Data)) {
      if (nchar(input$selectfiles) > 1){
        file <- paste0(input$selectfiles, ".RData")

        # FASTQ
        if (endsWith(input$selectfiles, ".fastq")){
          source("LoadFastQ.R", local = T)

        } else{

          # CSV
          source("LoadCSV.R", local = T)

        }
        # Force user to View tab once file is uploaded
        updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "DataView")
      }
    }
  })
```

CSV UI

```
output$CSV <- renderDataTable({
  datatable(
    CSV_table,
    filter = list(position = 'top'),
    class = 'cell-border strip hover',
    options = list(
      search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE),
      pageLength = 10
    )
  )
})

output$DataOutput <- renderUI({
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
             selectInput("CSV_identifier", "Identifier",
                         choices = c(colnames(CSV_table)),
                         selected = colnames(CSV_table)[1])
      ),
      column(
        12, offset = -1,
        dataTableOutput("CSV")
      )
    ),
      actionButton("clustbutton", "Clustering"),
      actionButton("corrbutton", "Correlation")
    )
  )
})
```

Selecting rows:

```
observeEvent(input$CSV_rows_selected, ignoreInit = T, {
  print("### NEW SELECT ###")
  print(input$CSV_rows_selected)
  CSV_selected <<- CSV_table[input$CSV_rows_selected, input$CSV_identifier]
  print(CSV_selected)
  print(dim(CSV_table))
})
```

Output when I click rows:

```
**click**
[1] "### NEW SELECT ###"
[1] 1                      # index of row in CSV
[1] "A"                    # value of index of row in CSV
[1]   22 1642              # dim(CSV)

**click**
[1] "### NEW SELECT ###"
[1] 1 2
[1] "A" "B"
[1]   22 1642

** Selecting new file **
**click**
[1] "### NEW SELECT ###"
[1] 1
[1] "A"
[1]   22 1642
[1] "### NEW SELECT ###"
[1] 1
[1] "X"
[1] 10  5

**click**
[1] "### NEW SELECT ###"
[1] 1 2
[1] "A" "B"
[1]   22 1642
[1] "### NEW SELECT ###"
[1] 1 2
[1] "X" "Y"
[1] 10  5
```

Example:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
packages <-
  c(
    "shiny",
    "DT",
    "data.table",
    "DESeq2",
    "fpc",
    "gplots",
    "SCAN.UPC",
    "digest",
    "shinyBS",
    "ggplot2",
    "reshape",
    "shinyjs",
    "squash"
  )
for (package in packages) {
  if (!package %in% installed.packages()){
    biocLite(package, ask = FALSE)
  }
  library(package, character.only = T)
}
rm(list=ls())
gc()

tableA <- data.frame(LETTERS[1:10], runif(10, 1, 100), stringsAsFactors = F)
tableB <- data.frame(LETTERS[11:20], runif(10, 1, 100), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "TEST", 
  id = "inTabset",

  # Tab 1 - Loading file
  tabPanel(
    title = "Load File",
    value = "loadfile",

    fluidRow(
      useShinyjs(),
      selectInput(
        "selectfiles",
        label = "Select loaded file",
        multiple = F,
        choices = c("tableA", "tableB"), selected = "tableA"
      )
    )
  ),

  # Tab 2 - View Data
  tabPanel(
    title = "View",
    value = "DataView",
    useShinyjs(),
    uiOutput("DataOutput")
  )
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # READ FILE AND RETURN DATA
  observeEvent(input$selectfiles, {
    # CSV
    CSV_table <- get(input$selectfiles)

    output$CSV <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(
        CSV_table,
        filter = list(position = 'top'),
        class = 'cell-border strip hover',
        options = list(
          search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE),
          pageLength = 10
        )
      )
    })

    output$DataOutput <- renderUI({
      fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
          column(4,
                 selectInput("CSV_identifier", "Identifier",
                             choices = c(colnames(CSV_table)),
                             selected = colnames(CSV_table)[1])
          ),
          column(
            12, offset = -1,
            dataTableOutput("CSV")
          )
        ),
        fluidRow(
          bsModal("clusterDESeqplotwindow", "DESeq clustering", trigger = "clusterDESeq", size = 'large',
                  plotOutput("clusterDESeqplot"),
                  downloadButton("clusterDESeqplotDownload")
          ),
          bsModal("clusterUPCplotwindow", "UPC clustering", trigger = "clusterUPC", size = 'large',
                  plotOutput("clusterUPCplot"),
                  downloadButton("clusterUPCplotDownload")
          ),
          bsModal("clustering", "Clustering", trigger = "clustbutton", size = "large",
                  fluidRow(
                    column(5,
                           textOutput("bsModal_selected_rows"),
                           br(),
                           htmlOutput("bsModal_Log")
                    ),
                    column(6, offset = 1,
                           fileInput("metadata", "Add metadata"),
                           selectInput("CSV_clusterparam", "Select DE parameter", choices = c(colnames(CSV_table)), selected = c(colnames(CSV_table))[2])
                    )
                    ,
                    div(id = "clusterButtons",
                        column(4, align="center",
                               actionButton("clusterUPC", "UPC"),
                               actionButton("clusterDESeq", "DESeq")
                        )
                    )
                  )
          ),
          actionButton("clustbutton", "Clustering"),
          actionButton("corrbutton", "Correlation")
        )
      )
    })


    observeEvent(input$CSV_rows_selected, ignoreInit = T, {
      print("### NEW SELECT ###")
      print(input$CSV_rows_selected)
      CSV_selected <<- CSV_table[input$CSV_rows_selected, input$CSV_identifier]
      print(CSV_selected)
      print(dim(CSV_table))
      output$bsModal_selected_rows <- renderText(paste("Selected samples:", paste(CSV_selected, collapse = ", ")))
    })
  })

  session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think you mean the [tag:datatables] tag or something else like that, not the one for the [tag:data.table] package.

Comment: I'm using the data.table package, but fair enough. The error isn't about the package itself.

Comment: Ok, up to you. Maybe it is related; I don't know any shiny but do know it supports some datatables thing is all.

Comment: No, you're right. I've removed the tag.

Comment: why doesn´t `reactive()`solve your issue? ( i think it does :) )

Comment: @BigDataScientist Because the observeEvent starts everything. After a file is changed it runs the whole UI for the CSV files. I've tried converting things to reactive, but reactive values need to be called afterwards, so I'd need an observer to check the changes anyway.
Could you give an example how you think `reactive()` would solve my issue?

Comment: then pls provide a reproducible example, that we can run the app and can try it out.

Comment: I've cleaned it up so it should mostly contain code related to the issue. Note, in the example it doesn't print out the first table's data after switching to the second table, but it still prints NULL (and runs twice after clicking 1 row in the second table)

Comment: hmm without the complete app you have to hope for smdy else i am afraid :/ Good luck!

Comment: The complete app won't help since it's not related to the CSV problem. All the code that I've put here is what is being ran after the program detects a CSV. I've tested it and it gives the same problems, so it should be enough :/

Comment: @BigDataScientist Please have a look at the given example. It should be runnable by itself and reproduce the error I have. Can you please show you you'd use `reactive()` to solve the problem? I have tried a few things but I'm not familiar enough with shiny's reactiveness to figure this problem out on my own :/

Comment: sry i cant help i get error messages for installing the packages for 10min. I hope someone can help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I was completely overthinking this.
Since the nested observe() was the problem, and trying to fix it with `reactive()` and `eventReactive()` and nothing working I came to the conclusion that I should just remove the `observeEvent()` calls from my LoadCSV.R script, bringing the observes outside of the observeEvent that I was using to check for my `selectinput()` element.

Now everything works as intended..